# CSS3 PIE: same style, different presentation

Tags: css, css3pie

I am using CSS3 PIE for make the box shadow property work in IE 8. As you can see in the image, I have 3 boxes with the same style, but only one of them (the first) is rendered as I want.

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="grid_22">
    <div class="panel_third">
        <!--WHATEVER-->
    </div>
    <div class="panel_third panel2">
        <!--WHATEVER-->
    </div>
    <div class="panel_third panel3">
        <!--WHATEVER-->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.panel_third{
   float: left;
   height: 317px;
   width: 206px;
   padding: 30px;
   margin-right:31px;
   background: #ffffff;
   position: relative;
   -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
   -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
   box-shadow:         0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);

   /**http://css3pie.com**/
   behavior: url(../../../../../dashboard/resources/main/js/libs/pie/PIE.htc);
}
.panel2{
  background: url(../img/Box-2-BG.png) no-repeat;
}
.panel3{
  background: url('../img/Box-3-BG.png') no-repeat;
  margin-right: 0;
  float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QV3GF/

Answer (score 0):

give it like this

```
.grid_22>div    
{
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
   -moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);
   box-shadow:         0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16);

   /**http://css3pie.com**/
   behavior: url(../../../../../dashboard/resources/main/js/libs/pie/PIE.htc);
}
```

it gives the shadow to all direct child div of .grid_22

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but doesn't work. I have the same result.

Comment: make a fiddle it will help any other too and we have some ease to play with the code